# How to define x-axis hover format when using plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly

In examples such as this one: https://plot.ly/12/~streaming-demos/, by using the designer tools under axes > Labels > Hover Format I am able to change the format of the time x-axis tooltip to something like "%y/%m/%d %I:%M%p"). How do I achieve the same thing in code?

I have been through the reference (https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/) and can't find anything on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. On the plotly designer there is a "View JSON" button which shows the json config object to achieve the effect I wanted.

The below code formats the x-axis (tickformat) and tooltip hover (hoverformat)

```js
var layout = {
  xaxis:{
    tickformat: "%y/%m/%d %I:%M %p",
    hoverformat: "%y/%m/%d %I:%M %p"
  }
}
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```